# Amazon S3 - expressjs read stream runs into timeout

Tags: javascript, express, amazon-s3, video-streaming, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to stream videos from an Amazon S3 Bucket.

Streaming works fine if I call my REST endpoint only once. But if I want to stream the video from multiple browsers at the same time, I get the following error:
*TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 120000ms*

My code so far:

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

app.get("/video", function(req, res, next) {
res.set({
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
    "Content-Length": 41811600,
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=31536000"
});

var stream;
if (req.headers.range) {
    const size = 41811600;
    const parts = req.headers.range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
    const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : size - 1;
    const length = end - start + 1;
    res.set({
    "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
    "Content-Length": length
    });
    stream = getReadStream(start, end);
} else {
    stream = getReadStream(undefined, undefined);
}
res.writeHead(res.getHeader("Content-Range") ? 206 : 200);
return stream.pipe(res);
});

function getReadStream(startByte, endByte) {
const params = {
    Bucket: "s3-fancy-test-bucket",
    Key: path.join(
    "SOME_KEY"
    ),
    Range: "bytes=" + (startByte || 0) + "-" + (endByte || "")
};
const stream = getS3Instance()
    .getObject(params)
    .createReadStream();
stream.on("error", err => {
    console.error(`Unable to get File Stream for ${params.Key} - ${err}`);
});
return stream;
}

function getS3Instance() {
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "ACCESS_KEY_ID",
    secretAccessKey: "SECRET",
    signatureVersion: "v4",
    region: "eu-central-1"
});
return new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: "2006-03-01" });
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

I'm not quite sure whether this is a problem with aws-sdk-js or a general problem with streams...

What am I doing wrong?
Is anyone experiencing the same problems?

Comment: Whats the reason for piping the video through node.js instead of just servering it directly from S3? You can always create a presigned S3 url, if it is for access restriction reasons. That is likely to give you a simpler setup.

Comment: Depending on the deployment environment (cloud / on premise) of our product, we either want to use S3 or the local file system for serving videos. That decision happens on the backend of the system so far.
But serving the videos from S3 directly is definitely an option if we won't be able to handle the current problems.

Comment: Makes sense, i don't know enough about node's handling of something like this unfortunately. Just felt it was strange having that proxy in there. But in your case, i can see how that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I've found out, that the behavior described above heavily depends on how the video is created. I'm using **ffmpeg** to convert videos to mp4. Converting videos with the **faststart** flag makes a big difference as far as the amount of range requests is concerned. Once I had the faststart flag in place there were a lot less range requests from the browser in order to load the video.
As there are fewer requests now, express / aws-sdk seem to be able to deal with it. There are no timeout any longer.

Answer (score 0):

We are trying exactly the same thing only the reason we are doing it is because we want to restrict access to the videos through our backend before streaming the video to the user. So serving videos directly from s3 is not an option. I realized that video is streamed just fine but getObject() times out 120000 ms(aws default timeout duration) even after the stream ends successfully. There seems to be an active issue regarding this on aws-sdk repository that is still not resolved.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2087